# Making Loco Translate Wordpress plugin to identify MU-PLUGINS

Tags: wordpress, localization

I'm using Loco Translate translation plugin with my Wordpress 4.7 installation.

I have my MU-Plugin correctly registered and properly configured to load its text domain.

Yet Loco Translate only manages to recognize themes and regular plugins, therefore I cannot use Loco Translate UI for translating my plugin.

Help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow Jonathan Darchy!

Here is an example of adding an unregistered MU plugin to Loco Translate
Raw, taken from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/timwhitlock/379c20d395bfe69965cc84563eb0eb13)

I think it answers your question:

```
<?php
/**
 * MU plugins inside directories are not returned in `get_mu_plugins`.
 * This filter modifies the array obtained from Wordpress when Loco grabs it.
 * 
 * Note that this filter only runs once per script execution, because the value is cached.
 * Define the function *before* Loco Translate plugin is even included by WP.
 */
function add_unregistered_plugins_to_loco( array $plugins ){
    // we know the plugin by this handle, even if WordPress doesn't
    $handle = 'foo-bar/foo-bar.php';

    // fetch the plugin's meta data from the would-be plugin file
    $data = get_plugin_data( trailingslashit(WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR).$handle );

    // extra requirement of Loco - $handle must be resolvable to full path
    $data['basedir'] = WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR;

    // add to array and return back to Loco Translate
    $plugins[$handle] = $data;
    return $plugins;
}
add_filter('loco_plugins_data', 'add_unregistered_plugins_to_loco', 10, 1 );
```